# Does The Same Layer 2 Routing Information From A Source End Up On The Other Side Of The Internet?

Tags: tcpdump, source-routing

when I do

```
tcpdump -e eth0
```

I get the traffic stream going through eth0, and I'm seeing various source MAC addresses of packets being received by eth0. I only have one default gateway connection with no switches in between. I thought MAC addresses were only used between single "hop" connections (including layer 2 devices). So then to what device/s might these various MAC addresses belong to?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your own and the router's MAC address, it's possible that you are seeing various [Multicast MAC addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet) or the broadcast MAC address (FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF).